# How to run spark jobs in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

reading data from kinesis which gets data for multiple tabes using spark streaming , to run jobs in parallel we have defined list and using par to run jobs in parallel

```scala
//read data from Kinesis

df.writestream.foreachBatch(runAllTables _)


tableList=List(1,2,3,4 ---500)

def runAllTables(batch_df: DataFrame, batchID: Long): Unit = {

tableList.par.map { table =>
//write data to target Oracle table 

 }

}
```

we have cluster with 8 executors , at anytime only 8 spark tasks are spinning up even though cluster is not used more than 5% , how to we spin up more tasks to run in parallel ? what we observed is its runs 8 jobs and goes for next 8 which is resulting in slow data processing .

Tried to use repartition or Future but there is no change in the behavior

Comment: What is the `spark.scheduler.mode`?

Comment: FAIR share scheduler